# Talis gift from child

Tags: halacha, tzitzis, minor-katan-child

If a child buys and gives a Talis as a present with money he earned, is the adult that wears it doing a Mitzvah D'oraisa each time ?

A Talis requires Tzitsis only if it is yours, but not if it belongs to someone else. [Shulchan Aruch 14/3]

In Choshen Mishpat [235/1-2]it is clear that M'dirabonon a child can sell or give a gift, but only if he doesn't have a "Apetrapus" manager.

The questions are:

1 - Does a child living by his parents have the same din as a child with an apitropus?
2  - Even if he can give a present, does that mean that it is considered the receivers for a Mitzva D'oraisa?

We do find by the esrog that receiving an esrog from a child can be problematic. [see Shulchan Aruch 658/6]

Comment: There is a well known question which is relevant in many places  whether קנין דרבנן מהני לדאורייתא - Can a kinyan which is valid only M'drabnan help for a mitzvah D'oraisa.

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore Among other places that comes up several times in Gittin, in the very sugyos on which the latter Shulchan Aruch is based.